# Implement REST service in gwt

Tags: rest, gwt, gwt-rpc

I want to implement **REST** service in gwt .But I don't know how to go about it. I read some documents where they have implemented it using **RestyGwt** and **jercy**. But I have one app which is deployed on tomcat. Then situation is that my client side app is calling the methods on the application present on tomcat.
I have to implement it using REST so that my client side call will first go to Proxy service on client then it make **REST** call to the application on tomcat and fetch result and return. How can I do this in gwt.  ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can only communicate with REST service.
Anyway, maybe take a look on dispatch concept in GWTPlatform and their way of implementing it. (https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Rest-Dispatch).

Idea is easy, you have an action on client side which is registered to deal with rest url. You can define action interface with some additional annotations to tell what is excepected to be send and received. They are using piriti library for json serialization.
It is up to you if you need only client side implementation or you would like to use server side service creation too.

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT implement a REST service in gwt, since gwt is thought as a client-side solution.

What the GWT kit provides for server side are a few utilities to facilitate the comunication between client-side and server-side when both are written in java (RPC, RF).

So you can consume a REST service from gwt (RequestBuilder, gwtquery-ajax, etc), but if you want to provide REST services you need a 3party solution for your server side like Jersey, CXF, etc.

There are, though, 3party solutions which provides the server side and client simultaneously like restygwt, errai-jax, etc.

If you are looking for a simple and reliable solution to query rest services from the client, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534864/gwt-rpc-vs-rest-is-it-really-one-or-the-other/17575966#17575966) you have a client implementation done with gwtquery (ajax, databinding, promises)