# GWT how to do async response with Http promise like in Play!Framework

Tags: gwt

I am coming from Play!Framework world into a GWT application.

I need to invoke an HTTP response from my GWT server.

In Play!Framework 1 I would simply "await" an WS.get.async result

```
Promise<HttpResponse> futureResponse = WS.url(
    "http://www.google.com"
).getAsync();
await(futureResponse);
```

And in play!framework2 I simply return an async response.

```
return async(
    WS.url(feedUrl).get().map(
    new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
        public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
            return ok("Feed title:" + response.asJson().findPath("title"));
        }
    }
)
);
```

both code snippets are from Play!Framework's documentation.

How can I achieve the same result in GWT backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like a "GWT server" or "GWT backend". If you're using GWT-RPC or RequestFactory, it's all servlet-based, without support for async processing; and GWT only provides the mean to process the client's requests, what you do on the server-side is entirely up to you, and is play Java (assuming GWT-RPC or RequestFactory, and their built-in implementations).

If you have an HTTP client library that returns a `java.util.concurrent.Future` (or something equivalent), then you can just do `return theFuture.get();` to wait for the HTTP request to complete.

Most HTTP client libs in Java a synchronous (blocking) though, so you don't even need to think about asynchronicity. If you want to do multiple things simultaneously, some libs can work async but many (if not most) use a callback rather than returning in `Future`. You can then use locks to await completion, or use something like Guava's `SettableFuture` (set its value from the callback, get its value when needed and it'll block until the value is set)

---

Note: most, if not all, other answers deal with client-side code, not server-side code as you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

GWT doesn't have  Promises, but you can use [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery) which apart from other features has a [Promises implementation](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Promises) based on [Promises/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/).

Edit: Notice that GWT is client-side centric, so this approach in just for the browser js runtime.

Your example could be written in this way:

```java
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
import com.google.gwt.query.client.*;

  // Using $$ to create a jso with the parameters for the ajax method
  // You can though use Settings.create() to use a java builder instead.
  Promise gettingInfo = ajax($$("url: rest_service.js, type: post, dataType: json, data: {foo: bar}"));

  // You can use the promise as many times as you need it, 
  // it would always maintain the status and server data.
  gettingInfo.done(new Function(){public void f() {
    Properties jsonResponse = arguments(0);
    Window.alert("Feed title:" + jsonResponse.get("title"));
  }});
```

Note that GQuery methods returns a Promise for certain methods (ajax, animations, etc).

In this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534864/gwt-rpc-vs-rest-is-it-really-one-or-the-other/17575966#17575966) there is another code example of using gquery promises.

Comment: I was told GQuery is for front-end development. I am looking for something to run in my backend. please confirm.

Comment: Well, GWT is a framework for client-side, it just uses java to produce javascript which is run in browser. GWT is agnostic to what you have in server side (rails, php, java, spring ...).

Comment: For server side, you can use any implementation of Future/Promises which run in the JVM, although gquery promises can run in JVM they are though for javascript apps. There are many java libraries with promises like jdeferred or even stuff in java jre like Future

Answer (score 0):

In GWT you need a lot of boiler plate code to do an Async Server Side call, and phylosophy is very different in GWT compare to Play

The only thing you can do is someting like :

```
myServiceAsync.myService(myRequest, new AsyncCallBack<myResponse>(){
    onSuccess(MyResponse response){
      // do your stuff
    }
    onFailure(Throwable e){...}
}
```

for this to work you need a lot of stuff:

1. a RemoteServlet that implements your service (Synchronous interface of point 2)
2. two interfaces one Synchronous and another Asynchronous
3. the instanciation of the Synchronous service on the client side that return the asynchronous version of your service

Hope it helps
Further explanation on GWT homepage : http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use GWTP https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/
It has a simple dispatch, with action response tuple that is easy to use.
Example: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/RPC-Dispatch

That code was forked from GWT-Dispatch: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/
That is also an alternative if you don't want to use a full MVP framework.