# Understanding REST with a GWT example

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, gwt

I am a newbie to RESTful services.
In my attempt to gain practical exp. with REST in GWT I am trying to create a simple GWT web-app.

The boiler plate code generated by GWT plugin in Eclipse is a nice working example but uses RPC mechanism to interact with backend. I would like to modify this app to use RESTful services.

So, far I have figured that I can use [RESTEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) server and [restyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/) to get this done. Also a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536862/768894) says that using Errai JAX-RS, building REST clients is as easy as implementing RPC, but this all seems too abstract to me.

Am I looking at the right tools for the job?

I am looking forward to any suggestion on how to proceed. Any sample code would be great.

Regrds,
Mohit

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend restyGWT from experience or the native GWT request factory. RestyGWT is very easy to setup and configure. You simply create an interface that mirrors your server implementation with the same annotations for @GET, @PUT, @PATH etc. The only difference is that you add a final argument to your interface implementation for a MethodCallback with the return. The only downside to this RestyGWT in my opinion is that it uses the GWT RPC for the implementation. This has caused some issues with me in the past when trying to add non white listed classes to the domain objects. You will run into issues where a class that is included is not serializable and cannot be transported to the browser client. It is my opinion to leave your rest services as they are and use requestfactory for the serialization and transport. RequestFactory does not suffer from the same white-listed class problems. It essentially uses a proxy interface on the client side that mirrors your server domain object implementation. RequestFactory can coexist with your back end rest services and use the same code as the Resource classes for retrieving the server side objects.

Here are the link to the gwt requestfactory documentation
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html

Here is restygwt's pizza example that is what I used to get started
http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html